comparing two rows with condition from another column
I have a table:



ticket_id
ticket_status
status_changing_date




a11f00
take to work
05:00:00


a11f00
closed
05:02:00



I want to find the difference (closing time - take to work time), that is 05:02:00 - 05:00:00. What script can I write? Or can this be done in Excel?
Thank you!

Your date column isn't a date, it's a string representing time.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have to assume some things about your table and your data, but this is one way to do it in SQL.
Your status_changing_date looks like a string representing time. Preferably you would work with actual timestamps. In this example I will generate them from the string using STR_TO_DATE().
First use GROUP BY to determine the take to work time and the closed time. Unsure how the rest of your data looks, so I will take the earliest (MIN) take to work time and the latest (MAX) closed time for now.
After this, use TIMEDIFF() to calculate the duration.
WITH time_per_ticket AS (
  SELECT 
    ticket_id, 
    MIN(CASE 
          WHEN ticket_status = 'take to work' 
          THEN STR_TO_DATE(status_changing_date, '%T') 
        END
    ) AS take_to_work_time,
    MAX(CASE 
          WHEN ticket_status = 'closed' 
          THEN STR_TO_DATE(status_changing_date, '%T')                  
        END
    ) AS close_time
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY ticket_id
)

SELECT ticket_id, TIMEDIFF(close_time, take_to_work_time) AS duration
FROM time_per_ticket

Check this https://dbfiddle.uk/YqAdQa8p
